# Creating a function using vba to workout vat

Tags: vba

Write a function to provide the VAT exclusive amount. We will assume that this is calculated by taking the Invoice_Price x 100/115. You can call this function VAT_Exl.

i need help with creating a function that will allow me to workout VAT Exclusive. when i was trying it i kept on getting #Value.
the reason why i use n as double, is because they didnt give us a figure.

```
Function VAT_Exl()
Const VAT_Amt=100/115
Dim n as Double

Select Case Invoice_Price
Case is >=n:Vat=(Invoice_Price*VAT_Amt)
end select

end function
```

Comment: What is `Invoice_Price`? What is `Vat`? What is `n`?

Comment: Your VAT rate is out of date. https://www.gov.uk/vat-rates

Comment: Earn your first badge - https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Your function should take in a parameter which is the Invoice Prive.  It should return a value which is the Invoice proces * 100/115.  No need for case statements or defining intermediate variables.  I suggest you start by reading up on how to declare a function.

Comment: We have to use a button and when we click the button it will ask for a figure and in the equation (Invoice_Price*100/115)....Invoice_Price is the figure to be calculated. VAT is Value Added Tax and in South Africa to calculate VAT Exclusive we have to multiply the amount by 100/115.

Comment: Invoice_Price has to be an amount that is required to fill in after we click on a button and inputBox appears. For example, when we click on a button, it will ask what is your VAT Amount? and then we say R120000*100/115=R104347,83......................so i need to make a funtion that will allow me to run that equation